# Using SQL Server Service Broker with multiple routes

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

When using the SQL Server Service Broker - if I had a service with two routes configured and I executed the `BEGIN DIALOG` statement **without** specifying the desired target broker instance, which of the possible destinations would it pick as the destination for the message?

I realise with `BEGIN DIALOG` I can explicitly target a specific broker, but this is only optional.  What would happen without it?  Would the message be sent to both routes?

Comment: Make sure you specify the target broker instance Id on each route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find the supporting documentation right now, but my memory says that it will choose one of the routes arbitrarily. It was meant as a means of being able to load balance among n databases that provide the same processing capability and you as the sender of the message don't care which of them actually does the processing.

Comment: Correct. Because Retries have to go to the same route the choice is not entirely arbitrary. It is based on a hash of conversation ID used as an index in the array of possible routes.

Comment: @remus - yes. Routing only happens for a new conversation. If you've already established a dialog with one particular database, you will continue to converse with the same. Of course, that is for the OP's edification, not yours (given that you *wrote* SB)!